# SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: angularjs

I am following Angular 2 quickstart [here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html)

I am getting following error on npm start:

```
angular-quickstart/bs-config.js:2
  "server": {
          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Here is my bs-config.json

```
{
  "server": {
    "baseDir": "src",
    "routes": {
      "/node_modules": "node_modules"
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.4.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2"
  }
}
```

I've latest node:

```
node -v
v7.5.0
```

And I've latest nam:

```
npm -v
4.1.2
```

Here is my directory structure:
    ls
    bs-config.js    node_modules    npm-debug.log   package.json    src

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bs-config.js` should be an JSON `bs-config.json` object.